# My addition logic not working in C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
 public partial class Addition : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        int Add1;
        int Add2;
        int answer;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Generates ramdom numbers for addition problem
        Random oRand = new Random();

        Add1 = oRand.Next(30);
        Add2 = oRand.Next(30);

        Label1.Text = Add1.ToString();
        Label2.Text = Add2.ToString();

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Validates users answer
        answer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);

        if (Add1 + Add2 != answer)
            Label3.Text = "InCorrect Answer";
        else
            Label3.Text = "Correct Answer";

        }
    }
```

I have been looking at this for the past 30 minutes and I know its something simple that I'm missing. When I execute the program and place the correct answer in TextBox1, Label3 still generates "InCorrect Answer." I know this is remedial but what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: When you debug the Button1_Click handler, do you see any values for Add1 and Add2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Add1 = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);
Add2 = Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text);

answer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);

if (Add1 + Add2 != answer)
  Label3.Text = "InCorrect Answer";
else
   Label3.Text = "Correct Answer";
```

Answer (score 3):

The user control is recreated upon postback (and upon every page load), so when you're setting the values of `Add1` and `Add2`, they get lost upon postback.

You should use the container `ViewState` or `Session` to hold these values.

EDIT:

Or as @IronMan84 suggests, just use the label (duh).